# List NPM libraries in NetBeans 8.2 maven java non-web app project

Tags: netbeans, npm, netbeans-8

When creating a web project, or an HTML5 project, there is a useful NetBeans feature enabled: a package.json editor which shows newer library versions, updates them etc:

[image: NPM package editor]

However, when I create a simple Maven Java project, this project property menu item is empty, even if package.json is present, "npm install" works and all other tools like Grunt work:

[image: No NPM]

How do I hint/make Netbeans to enable this function for a regular maven java project?

Even if it is a "simple" executable jar project, it will be able to serve web content like javascript and css by means that are out of my question's scope. Everything works except this handy feature to upgrade my NPM libs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a "webapp" directory in the "src/main", next to "java" directory. At least NetBeans 11 switches the npm project submenu on when this dir is present. Who would have known.

I have combined a skeleton project on GitHub, 
https://github.com/fedd/mavenwithnpm 
, but remember to create a `src/main/webapp` directory to see the package.json editor working. This folder should be ignored in git as it gets recreated all the time

Comment: Now started working again after some seemingly unrelated plugin update (Local Tasks I think)